# $\text{Nil}(R)=\text{rad}(0), I$ - prime ideal $\iff R/I$ integral domain, I - max ideal $\iff R/I$ field, and other questions on Ideals and Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

So I've analysed my last lecture in Commutative Algebra and those are the following questions I'd have:$\DeclareMathOperator{\Max}{Max}$

1. Like e.g. $I+J=\left\{a+b\::\:a\:\in \:I,\:b\:\in \:J\right\}$, is there a way to precisely define the elements in $\bigcap _{\alpha \in A}\:I_{\alpha }$?
2. As in the title, why is $\operatorname{Nil}(R) = \operatorname{rad}(0)$?
3. I - prime ideal $\iff R/I$ integral domain **and** $I$ - max ideal $\iff R/I$  is a field - Why? What's the proof for that?
4. We defined something as a multiplicative set S, which is if $1\in S, 0\notin S, a,b \in S$ then $ab \in S$. Why do we even bother to define something like that, what's the practical use and interpretation here?
5. Following that: If $I$ - prime ideal $\iff R/I$ multiplicative set, why?
6. If $I_n\subset I_{n+1}$ are all ideals, why is $\bigcup _{n\in N}\:I_n$ also an ideal?
7. We had such a theorem:

> Let $S\subset R$ be a multiplicative set and let $J$ be a family of ideals $I$ from ring $R$ so that $I\cap S=\varnothing $. Then $\forall _{I_0\:\in \:J}\:\:\exists \,{P\:\in \:J-\text{ prime and maximal ideal}},\:\:I_o \subset P$.

I kind of understand why P is a maximal Ideal (J fulfills Zorn's lemma thus if we take a chain of ideals so that $I_a\subset I_b$ and $a\le b$ we can say that $P = \bigcup _{\alpha \in A}\:I_{\alpha }$). But why is it also a prime ideal?

8. We had those statements and like to know why they are true:

- (a) If $f\::\:R\:\rightarrow \:T$ is an epimorphism, and $I\subset R$ is an ideal, then $f\left(I\right)$ is an ideal in T
- (b) If I take an ideal $J\supset I$, and $\pi :\:R\:\rightarrow \:R/I$ is an epimorphism, then $\pi \left(J\right)$ is also an ideal
- (c) The function $\pi$ is a bijection which retains the inclusion relation
- (d) $\left\{J\supset I\::\:J\:\in \Max\:R\right\}\ni L\:\rightarrow \:\pi \left(L\right)\in \:\left\{M\:\subset R/I\::\:M\:\in \:Max\:R/I\right\}$ is also a bijection which retains the inclusion relation (the same goes for Spec R and Spec R/I)
- (e) $I \in \Max\:R\:\Leftrightarrow \:\pi \left(I\right)=\left(0\right)\in \Max R/I \Leftrightarrow  R/I\text{ is a field}$

Sorry that it's so much but I would really really appreciate any effort here, I'm just curious and want to understand every detail and I'm not satisfied accepting something without a reason.

Comment: I disagree with both the downvote and the vote to close.  There's plenty of context here.

Comment: These are all fine questions to ask but a.) please limit to one question or a few closely related questions per post and b.) several of these question are answered in other places on this site. I would encourage you to consider your questions one by one, and if you can't find answers to them on this site already ask them individually.

Comment: I would post my questions separately if there wasn't a limit of 5 questions per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some answers (or questions):

1. What are the $I_\alpha$?
2. This is the definition of the nilradical. Remember the radical of an ideal $I$ of the ring $R$ is $\{x\in R\mid\exists\, n\in\mathbf N, \,x^n\in I\}$.
3. The definition of a prime ideal $I$ is that, for all $x,y\in R$, $xy\in I\implies x\in I\text{ or }y\in R$. Translated in terms of congruence classes modulo $I$, it becomes $\overline{xy}=\bar x\bar y=\bar x=\bar 0\implies \bar x=\bar0$ or $\bar y=\bar 0$, which corresponds to the definition of an integral domain.
   As to the maximality of the ideal $I$, a field can be characterised by the property that it has only two ideals  – $\{0\}$ and the field itself.
4. Multiplicative sets are the basis to defines rings of fractions od a given ring. Among these are the localisations of a ring at a prime ideal, which is an essential tool in algebraic geometry.
5. If $I$ is a prime ideal, it is not $R/I$ which is a multiplicative set, but $R\setminus I$
6. $\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbf N}I_n$ satisfies the properties defining an ideal – the sum of two elements of the union is in the union essentially because by hypothesis, the set of ideals is totally ordered by inclusion.
7. A maximal ideal is also a prime ideal (because, considering the quotient $R/I$, a  field is an integral domain).

Comment: 1. Ideals, I'm talking about how the elements of an intersection of ideals would precisely look like 2. Yes, that's the definition of a Nilradical, and I don't get it why Nil(R) = rad(0) 3. Why does a field only have 2 ideals? 4. Can you maybe tell me an example? 5. So in other words R : I, right? But why? 6. Ok I think I understand it, it's because the set of ideals is ordered by inclusion by definition 7. But we are not in R/I, but in R? Does it have anything to do with that I_0 and S are disjoint sets?

Comment: There is no general answer to question 1, except being made up of the elements which belong to each $I_\alpha$. For P.I.D.s, there maybe an answer if the family of ideals is finite: it is the principal ideal generated by the l.c.m. of the generators of the ideals. For question2, it is implicit in my answer: a nilpotent element

Comment: 3. As every nonzero element in a field has an inverse, a nonzero ideal necessarily contains $1$, so it is the entire field. A classic example in 4, is is the ring R_f$, where $f$ is an element  $R. In 5, I don't know what you  denote $R:I$, but I mean the elements of the ring which do not belong to $I$. In 7, I mention the fact that maximality or primality of an ideal  can be expressed in terms of the quotient ring by this ideal.

Comment: 2. So what exactly is the answer? Because I don't understand 3. Ok I understand it 4. What is R_f? Literally see it for the first time 5. Ok, my bad, but why is it a multiplicative set then? 7. But we don't deal with a integral domain R here, R is an arbitrary ring

Comment: 2. Nilradical or Rad(0) are just two slightly different ways to express the  same notion, $R_f$  is the set of fractions with denominator a power of $f$. 5. It is a multiplicative set because $a\notin I$ and $b\notin I$ imply $ab\notin I$ (this is the contrapositive of the property defining a prime ideal) 7. An arbitrary ring can perfectly have integral domains or fields as quotients  (example: $\mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z$ and the ideal $2\mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z$ – the quotient is the field with two elements.

Comment: 2. Rad(I) means that its the set of numbers such that there exists an exponent n so that r^n belongs to our ideal I, I understand that Rad(0) is of the radical of an ideal generated by 0? 5. So you say that the definition of a multiplicative set is like the "opposite" of a prime ideal? That if a and b do not belong to I then it's product also doesn't belong to I? 7. Yes but nevertheless, we have a ring R here, and we just showed that due to Zorn's Lemma it's a maximal ideal. But it also is a prime ideal our prof said. And I just lost the connection to why it is also a prime ideal

Comment: Yes (almost) Rad (0) is the radical of *the* ideal $(0)$. 5. Yes, at least for the complement of a prime ideal. A maximal ideal is also prime because when you consider the quotient $R/I$, being a field implies being an integral domain.

Comment: 5. Ok. But what I don't get is how can this be the same thing? Nil(R) means all the elements of an arbitrary ring R so that there exists an n such that x^n = 0 (neutral additive element), on the other hand Rad(I) just means that it's the set of numbers so that there exists a n such that x^n is an element of I. For me those are two completely different concepts, I can see if R = I (so here in this place R = (0), is this always the case for any arbitrary R?) that $Nil\left(R\right)\subset Rad\left(0\right)$, but I don't see why $\supset$ is also true

Comment: 7. Ok I can see why because as you already elaborated a field only has two ideals. But we are still not (!) considering R/I, so we are not necessarily moving in a field. What we are still talking about is that our maximum ideal is also a prime ideal in R (not R/I), so we cannot say that "R is a field thus our ideal which we've found is also maximal an not only that, because a field is also a integral domain this ideal we've found is a prime ideal". In other words: We do not have a guarantee here that R is even an integral domain

Comment: Of course, $R$ is not necessarily an integral domain. It's all about the quotient $R/I$. I only used that properties of $I$ as an ideal of $R$ are reflected as properties of $R/I$.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But what about Nil(R) = Rad(0) now?

Comment: Do you see any difference between  $a^n=0$ and $a^n\in \{0\}$?

Comment: As stated above: Nil(R) means all the elements of an arbitrary ring R so that there exists an n such that x^n = 0 (neutral additive element), on the other hand Rad(I) just means that it's the set of numbers so that there exists a n such that x^n is an element of I. For me those are two completely different concepts, I can see if R = I (so here in this place R = (0), is this always the case for any arbitrary R?) that ()⊂(0), but I don't see why ⊃ is also true. So yes, I see a difference

Comment: Just because the definition of the second is just a reformulation of the definition of the first. You seem to forget that the ideal generated by $0$ is just $\{0\}$ – its single element is $0$ itself.

Comment: Aaa ok now I get it thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome!